# Restriction on getting IMEI number with 10+ version on android device, any other unique number available?

Tags: android-10.0, imei

In the latest version 10 and above in an android device developers cannot access the IMEI number, not even they can use this permission:-

**android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE**

then is there any other unique number available that is visible on the user's android device and also can get programmatically?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: not actually helpful @CommonsWare

Comment: It outlines your available options for standard versions of Android.

Comment: But I need a unique number that also gets from an android device not just programmatically but I need something which I can get manually too, that is my concern

Comment: What does "I can get manually too" mean?

Comment: I mean we can get the IMEI number programmatically below device android Q right also we can get the IMEI number by checking on the android device itself too right? Like that, I'm looking for any solution with and above device having version Q on android devices.

Comment: "also we can get the IMEI number by checking on the android device itself too right?" -- that might vary by manufacturer and device. I certainly would not assume that the IMEI is always independently accessible. "I'm looking for any solution with and above device having version Q on android devices" -- AFAIK, that does not exist, for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the IMEI number, I found androidId which can work on all devices including android 10 and 11.